# Get Integer from HTML text to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I have a text field like this:

```
<input id="num" type="text" style="width:10px"/>
```

I am trying to retrieve it from JavaScript as follows:

```
var numofnodes =parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value,10);
```

It is giving "", and i tried like this

```
var numofnodes =document.getElementById('num').value
```

But still I am getting `""`.

Comment: What is the value in the field?  What were you expecting?

Comment: I am giving a number say 100

Comment: Any chance that the document has more than one element with the `id="num"` attribute? Any errors in the console?

Comment: It does not contain any element with id=num, I am using visual studio so i saw by using a break point and found that the numofnodes=""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem seems that you are trying to read the value on page load, i.e. textbox isn't having any value given, hence you get blank:

```js
var numofnodes = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10);
alert(numofnodes);
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" style="width:10px" />
```

Try with `value` attribute for default no. of nodes:

```js
var numofnodes = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10);
alert(numofnodes);
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" style="width:10px" value="100" />
```

Comment: I moved the statement to function body that handles submit click event it works

Answer (score 0):

parseInt either returns an integer or NaN, it shouldn't be a "". How do you output the value that you get? Your code seems to works fine for me:

```
<input id="num"  type="text" style="width:100px"/>
<button id="b">log value</button>
```

...

```
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function()  {
  console.log( parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10) );
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVMzxr?editors=101

Comment: The above code is not working,
I am using the variable numofnodes in some loop,

Comment: I get NaN when I try to output it in a div. I can't seem to use the value as integer.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried your code, and for me it works correctly.**

```
<input id="num" type="text" style="width:10px;" value=100 />
```

added value into attribute

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // print into console as int
    var numofnodes =parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value,10);
    console.log(numofnodes);

    // print into console as string
    var numofnodes =document.getElementById('num').value 
    console.log(numofnodes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, surprisingly enough, no one mentioned the event's built-in property for this.

```
event.target.valueAsNumber
```

will give the value as a `number` for inputs with type `number` without any conversions.